# where to get jquery image sprites?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-tools

Ok I know this sounds like  a stupid question but I JUST CAN NOT find the answer (maybe cause its just soo stupid? )

anyways I just made an overlay using jquery tools and I JUST CANNOT figure out where to get the close button image? its just not there? the functionality is there (i.e if I click the top right the overlay closes)but not the button.

I googled and finally figured out that jquery Image sprites were not downloaded properly. but where do I download the jquery sprites from :/ ??? I checked the jquery tools download page http://www.jquerytools.org/download/ but you only download the .js file from there, no images no nothing?

Am I missing something? Cause its a bit hard to believe that they dont give a close image for their overlay :/..

Comment: I usually do image sprites with CSS, not javascript. That is only a personal remark. :) By the way, is there someone who can tell me if  it is common to do that in javascript, though?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to: http://www.jquerytools.org/documentation/tabs/index.html
Scroll down at tabs Graphics
You have a zip image. Click there.
It's a zip with images :)